# How do I use the corresponding number to make the selection in a dropdown instead of using the mouse?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I looked at the information and it is just showing how to create the dropdown which I can do but I want to be able to type 1 and have it come up Very Poor, or 2 and have it come up with Poor, 3 Average, 4 Good, 5 Very good. Do you know how to do this to simplify the selections without having to keep pressing the dropdown arrow and making a choice if you know the corresponding number.

Comment: In order to help you, it would be helpful to know what "*information*" you looked at, how you created the dropdown you are currently working with, and what you have tried so far to achieve the results you desire.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `Data Validation` feature in Excel, you can use the keyboard by holding the `Alt` key and pressing the `Down` arrow. Then you can let go of `Alt` and use the arrows to make your selection.

Otherwise, if this is a table of data, I tend to rely on Excel's built-in auto-suggestion based on previous entries in the table.